# CSS loading but not working properly in MVC 4 IIS 10

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have just changed my PC from Windows 7 32bit, IIS 7.5 to Windows 10 64bit, IIS 10. I have added all the files on WWWRoot, enabled Common Static Features - Static content in IIS.

When I am browsing my project from localhost, it is loading all css, js, images properly but CSS not applying properly but image is loading from the same CSS file. CSS file not working properly from any browser (Chrome, Edge, IE). Everything fine in my old PC.

What do I need to do to get my CSS files to work properly?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the CSS files are exactly the same, no files missing, no console errors, the order of loading is the same? Also please provide some screenshots and/or information about your project. Do you work with LESS/SASS or other techniques we should know. etc.

Comment: @ArnoTenkink, I am absolutely sure, there are no errors, no file missing, the order is same in both pc's. I am not working any LESS/SASS, this is a MVC  4 project and I just changed my pc

Comment: @ArnoTenkink, its only the css not working properly in the new pc, but old pc is same, I have followed everything exactly from old pc to new pc

Comment: @ArnoTenkink, I think it is related something with IIS 10 but not sure what it is

Comment: Did you look at the browser developer console? Are the css files being requested/delivered?

Comment: @Locke125, yes, developer console showing the css files same as my old pc and new pc, but some reason new pc's css not working properly

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that `Serve Static Content` is enabled in IIS?

[image]

Comment: Yes, I did but no luck

Comment: If you have access to the old PC or a co-worker that has this working can you check the IIS features enabled and make sure you have everything enabled/installed?

Comment: Yes, I tried my best to check the IIS features in both pc's but did not find any difference

Comment: What is the http status code for your missing css files are showing under the network tab in your web dev browser console?

Comment: It is not missing, its loading but not working properly, like css classes not working, status code is showing 200

Comment: Are the MIME Types correct? You might also check the event viewer to see if there are any errors. I've also seen a similar issue when a .net site ins't set to integrated mode, has a wrong version of .net, or there is an issue with the .net setup.

Comment: MIME type I have .css type - text/css, i am not sure about .net setup, i think I follow the correct way, now I am trying to re-install the VS and setup project again